# Not able to open prompt using .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)

Tags: azure, desktop-application, prompt, azure-authentication, msal

I am implementing MSAL in my windows application. i want to open a windows prompt to open to select the account.
when I hover on Prompt in code i see below error
[image]

The prompt does not open at all.

below is the code I am using

```
    private async Task CallGraph()
        {
            var _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(id)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "somevalue")
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var app = _clientApp;
            //ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
            //TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, 

firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
                // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {                   
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    //.WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
                    //.WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();                   
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
        {

            TraceLogging.LogException($"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}", ex);


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TraceLogging.LogException($"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}", ex);
        return;
    }

   

 if (authResult != null)
    {
        await GetHttpContentWithToken(graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
        string res = $"Username: {authResult.Account.Username}" + Environment.NewLine;
        //DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
        //this.SignOutButton.Visibility = 

Visibility.Visible;
            }

            }
            public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var request = new 

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return content;
            }

   

 catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to implement msal for both desktop and web app .Please let me know for any more details or any sample application which uses asp .net and not dotnet core

Comment: .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault()) ,i removed this line and the error does not come shown in screenshot.However the prompt does not open

Comment: Could you include your complete code to acquire token by editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application by adding **redirect URI** in *Mobile & Desktop applications* platform and **enabled** public-client flow:

[image]

Now, I created one Windows Forms App(.NET Framework) and replaced the below files with following code:

**Form1.cs**:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GraphApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += Form1_Load; // Subscribe to the Form Load event
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Add any initialization code here if needed
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CallGraph();
        }

        private static async Task CallGraph()
        {
            var clientId = "appId";
            var _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "tenantId")
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var app = _clientApp;

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token:{Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{Environment.NewLine}{ex}");
                return;
            }

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Username: {authResult.Account.Username}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**:

```cs
namespace GraphApp
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 90);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Call Graph";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

When I ran the application now and clicked on <kbd>**Call Graph**</kbd> button, prompt came to pick an account like this:

[image]

While signing in, it asked me to **consent** the permissions with below screen:

[image]

After accepting the consent, I got the pop-up with signed-in user's **Username** successfully like this:

[image]